# Nodejs fails in sublime

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2

I have installed sublime2, package control module and nodejs through it.
After opening my js application I am getting next error, when try to run my application Tools->NodeJS->Run.

`File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 445, in is_enabled_
    raise ValueError("is_enabled must return a bool", self)
ValueError: ('is_enabled must return a bool', <Nodejs.Nodejs.NodeUglifyCommand object at 0x10f70bc90>)`

All items in the menu are disabled.

Also I have tried modify user settings use next one:

```
    {
  // save before running commands
  "save_first": true,
  // if present, use this command instead of plain "node"
  // e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"
  "node_command": "/usr/local/bin/node",
  // Same for NPM command
  "npm_command": "/usr/local/bin/npm",
  // as 'NODE_PATH' environment variable for node runtime
  "node_path": "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.25",

  "expert_mode": false,

  "ouput_to_new_tab": false
}
```

I have installed node via brew.

Comment: When you do `which node` in the terminal, do you get "/usr/local/bin/node"?

Comment: @Frax yes, `which node` returns `/usr/local/bin/node`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with my custom build system. The solution is just to choose the build system you want to use.
There must be checkmark alongside some build system in Tools->Build System

Comment: Any suggestions for windows: {
  // save before running commands
  "save_first": true,
  // if present, use this command instead of plain "node"
  // e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"
  "node_command": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe",
  // Same for NPM command
  "npm_command": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\npm.cmd",
  // as 'NODE_PATH' environment variable for node runtime
  "node_path": false,

  "expert_mode": false, 

  "ouput_to_new_tab": false
}

Comment: @Félix sorry, but I don't understand the question

Comment: I share your point of view, the best available solution out there comes with custom build system, my goal is to achieve it by the plugin itself. Also, I've contacted by tweeter with the developer. The repo is discontinued, a shame.